# AutoMapper: Store navigation properties to intermediate result for mapping

Tags: automapper

In my below mapping I have to check for the existing of the navigation property and based on it I have to map the properties

```
.ForMember(x => x.IsReceived, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.DropOff.Contamination.Any(c => c.EquipmentId == x.EquipmentId && c.IsValidated.GetValueOrDefault())))
.ForMember(x => x.ReceivedOn, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.DropOff.Contamination.Any(c => c.EquipmentId == x.EquipmentId && c.IsValidated.GetValueOrDefault()) ? x.DropOff.Contamination.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EquipmentId == x.EquipmentId && c.IsValidated.GetValueOrDefault()).MeasurementDate : null))
.ForMember(x => x.Receiver, opt => opt.MapFrom((x) => x.DropOff.Contamination.Any(c => c.EquipmentId == x.EquipmentId && c.IsValidated.GetValueOrDefault()) ? new LookupItem<string, string>
{
    Id = x.DropOff.Contamination.Single(c => c.EquipmentId == x.EquipmentId && c.IsValidated.GetValueOrDefault()).ReceivedBy,
    Value = FormattingHelper.GetStaffDisplayName(x.DropOff.Contamination.Single(c => c.EquipmentId == x.EquipmentId && c.IsValidated.GetValueOrDefault()).ReceivedByNavigation, null)
} : new LookupItem<string, string>()))
```

But you can see I have to repeat this object selection check every time for all the properties

```
x.DropOff.Contamination.Single(c => c.EquipmentId == x.EquipmentId && c.IsValidated.GetValueOrDefault())
```

Is there any way in auto mapper to store this object temporarily and use it for multiple properties rather selecting it this way everytime?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - This will not work for my case. Because it is not just the mapping definition in my case but selecting the particular navigation object

Comment: You can write anything you want inside the `IncludeMembers` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @LucianBargaoanu in comment I used `IncludeMembers` and it worked perfectly!

This is how I implemented it now

I included the property like this with the original map definition

```
CreateMap<DropOffBarcodedEquipment, DropOffEquipmentBase>()
    .IncludeMembers(x => x.DropOff.Contamination.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EquipmentId == x.EquipmentId && c.IsValidated.GetValueOrDefault()))
```

And then added mapping from `Contamination` to `DropOffEquipmentBase`

```
CreateMap<Contamination, DropOffEquipmentBase>()
    .ForMember(x => x.IsReceived, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.MeasurementDate.HasValue))
    .ForMember(x => x.ReceivedOn, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.MeasurementDate))
    .ForMember(x => x.Receiver, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => new LookupItem<string, string>()
    {
        Id = x.ReceivedBy,
        Value = FormattingHelper.GetStaffDisplayName(x.ReceivedByNavigation, null)
    }));
```

And this combination works like a charm!

Thanks to @LucianBargaoanu